# Video Zooms When Put on Face

Tags: texturing, uv, video

I've been making a marvel-type intro and have got to the part where I'm adding the videos. However, when I add the video as the texture for a face, for some reason it shows up zoomed in. I'm not really sure why it does this.
(I'm pretty new to Blender)
[image: Image of the texture on the face]
[image: Image of the preview + the UV edit]